# PHP_SELF returns /index.php/index.php

Tags: php, nginx

Why does `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` return `/index.php/index.php` ??

## request

```
http://example.com
```

## output

```
/index.php/index.php
```

## index.php

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

## nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    root  /var/www/public/www;

    # Add trailing slash
    rewrite  ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    location / {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/public/www/index.php;
    }
}
```

## fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works..

If you change the order in `fastcgi.conf` it works and the correct values are returned by `PHP_SELF` and `SCRIPT_NAME`

`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` is moved to the top of the file

## fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a **known issue** (link [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55208)) when using nginx with php-fpm:

> When setting SCRIPT_NAME to something, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will contain 
>   PHP_SELF environment value concatenated with environment value of SCRIPT_NAME.